# How do I filter related Child Record

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ria

I am using RIA services. I need to select a parent entity (`UnitOccupier`) which has a number of related child entities(`UnitOccupierDetails`). I need to filter the child entities to return a single record. How do I do this?

```
var q = from uo in _unitOccupierContext.GetUnitOccupierQuery()
        where uo.UnitOccupierDetails.????
                                     ---> I cant get to the child properties here
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot include a filtered child collection of the selected parent. You can only include either the full collection or no child collection at all. But as a workaround you could use an intermediate anonymous type, like so:

```
var q = (from uo in _unitOccupierContext.GetUnitOccupierQuery() 
         select new {
             Parent = uo,
             Childs = uo.UnitOccupierDetails
                        .Where(uod => uod.MyDetailsProp == MyDetailsValue)
         }).FirstOrDefault();

if (q != null)
{
    UnitOccupier selectedUnitOccupier = q.Parent;
    selectedUnitOccupier.UnitOccupierDetails = q.Childs.ToList();
    // selectedUnitOccupier now only contains the filtered childs
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to query for the childs and include their parents (related to question in comment) you could use:

```
var q = _unitOccupierContext.GetUnitOccupierQuery()
         .SelectMany(uo => uo.UnitOccupierDetails
                             .Where(uod => uod.MyDetailsProp == MyDetailsValue))
         .Include(uod => uod.UnitOccupier)
         .FirstOrDefault(); // or .ToList() if you expect more than one record
// q is now null or a single UnitOccupierDetails entity
// with a reference to its parent
```

I am assuming here that your `UnitOccupierDetails` class has a navigation property to the parent `UnitOccupier`.

Comment: Can I query the child and include the parent?

Comment: Thanks for the update - I tried querying the OwnerOccupierDetails entity and filtering it to the entity I need. That works fine until you come to save the entity, because it needs its parent and cause referential errors in the database. I am going to retry with you code above...

Comment: OK -I am struggling a bit. Firstly, yes UnitOccupierDetails DOES have a UnitOccupier Navigation property.