# LINQ: filter child objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

When accessing a database via the Entity Framework I have three entities available:

- stt_dictionary
- stt_concept
- stt_term

Each of these entities has a collection of a fourth entity, stt_change_log.

So for example,

```
stt_dictionary.stt_change_log = ICollection<stt_change_log>
```

The relationship between those top 3 elements and the stt_change_log is

```
stt_change_log.element_id = (stt_dictionary | stt_concept | stt_term).id;
```

However, as stt_dictionary, stt_concept and stt_term all have *int* as their ID type, the following is also needed:

```
stt_change_log.element_type_id = (7 | 8 | 9)
```

Now, when I run a query like below, it returns all stt_change_log entities with the specified ID, which means that if I want stt_change_log entities when stt_dictionary.id = 1, I also get stt_change_log entries pertaining to the stt_concept and stt_term entities whose ID also = 1. In other words, the stt_change_log collection needs additional filtering.

```
var daoDictionary = (from d in db.stt_dictionary
                         .Include("stt_change_log.stt_change_types")
                     where d.id == id
                     select d).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I filter the stt_change_log entities by specifying a value for the element_type_id property for each item in the stt_change_log collection?

I'll also add that my intention is to do this in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately .Include does not allow filtering.

You can [use a projection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5666403/141172) to perform filtering server-size, or you can lazy load the items as needed.

You can also [vote for that feature](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/47) to be included in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response, Eric. I don't actually need that first .Include statement as that level of children is populated by an association. However, even though there's an association between stt_change_log and stt_change_types, the stt_change_log.stt_change_type property doesn't get automatically populated (I don't know why). 
So, as the .Include statement is only there for the next level down (not the level that I want to filter on), does that work in my favour? Does that mean that there *is* something I can do on the stt_change_log collection?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to use table-by-hierarchy (TBH) inheritance mapping for your log entity.  You would define a base entity stt_change_log, then derive an entity class for each type of log.  The stt_change_type would be the discriminator.

Then each of your 'main' entities would reference the log type specific to that entity and the filtering is magically done for you ;)

Read the following tutorial to get started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292

Note that in your situation you would not need any additional properties in your derived entities.  If you're using code first, search for "table by hierarchy code first"; here's a quick ready: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/17/code-first-ef-4-1-table-per-hierarchy.aspx

Comment: TPH Inheritance does indeed look to be just what I need. But after having spent about 3 hours on it, I just can't get it to work - too many build errors. I followed the example at your first link (I'm not using Code First) but the difference between the model used in the example and my model is that mine has far more associations. Specifically, there are associations on the entity that it tells me to mark as abstract (and inherit from), and those associations are no longer valid once I've inherited new entities from the stt_change_log entity. A pity, as TPH looks very useful.